# Python: Internet Content Adaptation Protocol(ICAP) client implementation in python

Tags: python, proxy, client

I need to write an **ICAP**(Internet Content Adaptation Protocol used by proxies) client in python so i was wondering if anyone knows of some Python implementation for it. I searched but have not found any. Found only a C implementation of an ICAP server which has client APIs in it. But no python implementation. Can anybody suggest anything cool?

Comment: The first google result:  http://icap-server.sourceforge.net/#_TOC22

Comment: @wim, This is a server in python NOT a client. For the client side they are providing a patched version of squid.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but those two should help you:

- https://github.com/uditha-atukorala/bitz-server/blob/master/test/icap-client.py
- http://code.peternixon.net/icappy/src/86f8d5981d30c981892b88d02184c586383c1ca0/icapclient.py

The first one is very static but also verbose to understand the protocol, second one build on top of twisted.